# Fairies are not respawning

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I currently have 3 Fairies that I got from a Great Fairy Fountain. However, I've since opened up two other Great Fairy Fountains and neither of those had fairies around them. I've been playing quite a while and I haven't had them respawn at the first great Fairy Fountain either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fairies will only respawn if you have less than 3 Fairies.

The number of Fairies that respawn at each Fountain are as follows:

Fairies Left : Fairies at Fountain
3+ : 0
2 : 1
1 : 2
0 : 3

So, release all three fairies and 3 Fairies will spawn at each Fountain, which will allow you to have up to 12 Fairies at once.

Comment: Nice tip! I wondered, why none reappeared. Although I think I got 4 from the first fountain....

Comment: There are also faeries on the top of the Great Deku tree!

Comment: I saw a bunch pop up after doing some marathon grass-cutting in a field. I got 2 in 2 minutes!

Comment: I've seen way more than 3 fairies at the Kakariko Village fairy fountain... however, several of them were out of reach.

Comment: Yesterday I used up some fairies, had 1 left. Went back to Kakariko and found 4 fairies at the fountain. With stealth clothes it is very easy to just walk up to the fairies and collect them. If they are too high up, just wait below them and they will come to you sooner or later.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because it contains wrong information about the mechanics on how fairies spawn and how many spawn. Please edit this answer to correct it.

Comment: You actually don't need to "release" your existing Fairies. You just need to "hold" them, and new Fairies immediately spawn, at least for me. I then dropped what I hold and immediately picked them up. I assume one can go into Inventory and cancel the "hold" for safety.

Answer (score 2):

Fairies can only spawn if you have less than 3 fairies in your inventory.

Fairy fountains always spawn 4 fairies, though it takes some time until a fairy that you caught, or that flew away, can spawn again.

Since the game only counts the fairies in your inventory it is possible to hold some in your hand, in order to reduce the amount of fairies in your inventory to under 3, to make more fairies spawn and get considerably more.

[How to hold 11 fairies at once](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/60xd0d/botw_guide_how_to_hold_11_fairies_at_once_max/)

Comment: Does someone know when fairies respawn?
Is it during blood moons?
Is it different depending on if you catch them, or if they fly away?