# Only one Fairy spawning at fairy fountains - no Fairies in inventory

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

For the last week I haven't been able to get more than one Fairy to spawn at fountains. It seems the game thinks I already have fairies in my inventory, but I don't. I'm trying to stock up to make fighting the Thunderblight Ganon a little easier.

Comment: I've also seen people mention that enough time must pass since the last time you got them; and a good indication of whether enough time passed is to go check after a blood moon.

Comment: I don't know why people closed this, but this *isn't* a duplicate.  OP clearly indicated that they have no fairies, but the answer to the other question indicates the fairies are only limited by the number you have collected already.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question can be answered with "it is an intended game mechanic", while this one appears to be about a bug

Answer (score 1):

I read on some post somewhere (I apologize, I can't find the post. If I can find the post again I'll edit my answer to include a link) that sometimes if you have been playing your system for a long time without actually turning it off (really off, not just sleep mode) then some things, including fairies, won't respawn after the blood moons. Try saving your game, turning off the switch, and then turning on the switch again and then playing the game again (you may still have to wait for a blood moon though).

If you are looking to maximize the number of fairies you have, there are tricks (see [this link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303622/fairies-are-not-respawning?noredirect=1&lq=1) which refers you to [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/60xd0d/botw_guide_how_to_hold_11_fairies_at_once_max/) for example) in order to get 11 in your bag.
**Edit:** The trick basically is to collect 3 fairies from the first fountain, then go towards the second fountain but before you get to the area hold 2 fairies so you only have 1 in your bag (which should allow 4 fairies to spawn, under normal game mechanics) and then put away the fairies you're holding and collect the 4 fairies that spawned, then go to the third fairy fountain but before you get there hold 5 fairies so you only have 2 in your bag (which should allow 4 fairies to spawn, under normal game mechanics) and then put away your fairies and collect the 4 fairies that spawned. This should bring your total to 11 fairies.

Comment: Can you give a quick description of those tricks just in case the link get's changed?

Comment: @Robbie, Thanks for the suggestion! I have added some details of the tricks the links mention, in case the links change.